# ¿Como puedo refactorizar estos callbacks usando async/await?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo esta serie de métodos los usan callbacks y los cuales dependen del resultado del otro metodo para poder continuar con el flujo normal. 
/////
Quiero hacer el flujo más legible con async/await pero no tengo claro cómo hacerlo.

Estoy trabajando con angular.

de ante mano gracias por su ayuda.

```js
function http (a,resolve,reject){
    // metodo que realiza una peticion a la base de datos 
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if(a.user == 'j'){
            resolve('el usuario existe en base de datos')
        }else{
            reject('no existe')
        }
    },3000)
    

}

//archivo 2
 function authUser (f, user,clave){
    // metodo que arma el objeto para hacer una peticion http

    let objeto = {
        user,
        clave
    }

    
    http(objeto,
        (response) => {
            f(response)
        },
        (error) =>{
            console.log(error);
        } 
    )

}


//archivo 1
authUser(colocaRespueta, 'j','a')

function colocaRespueta(response){
    console.log(response);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async function http (a){
    // metodo que realiza una peticion a la base de datos 
   try {
      const a = await // Tu consulta en la DB
      if(a.user == 'j') {
        return 'el usuario existe en base de datos';
      }
   } catch (e) {
     return undefined;
   }
}

//archivo 2
 async function authUser (f, user,clave){
    // metodo que arma el objeto para hacer una peticion http

    let objeto = {
        user,
        clave
    }

    const response = await http(objeto)
    if(response){
      f(response)
    }


}
```

Comment: Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Entiendo que los comentarios en el código pueden ser de ayuda, pero implican leer entre lineas. Por favor, si puedes edita tu respuesta y agrega alguna argumentación adicional. Recuerda que tu respuesta no la lee únicamente el OP. Puedes leer [answer]. Saludos